# ssh -V shows OpenSSH_7.6, but openssh not installed

Tags: server, ssh, openssh

On Ubuntu Server 18.04, if I run:

```
ssh -v
```

it returns

```
OpenSSH_7.6p1, without OpenSSL
```

but

```
sudo apt-get remove openssh-server openssh-client
```

returns

```
package 'openssh-client' is not installed, so not removed
package 'openssh-server' is not installed, so not removed
```

I did some mistakes while trying to install an older version of OpenSSH, now can't get this to work anymore. When I try to install openssh-server I always have an error.

One of the steps I did run to install older OpenSSH verison, even if I've to admit I'm not sure I used all these options :(

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc/ssh --with-privsep-path=/var/empty --libexecdir=/usr/lib/openssh --without-openssl
```

The errors that I get when I try to install again OpenSSH:

```
dpkg error processing package openssh-server (--configure)
installed openssh-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 255
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error
```

Comment: Add the output of `type -a ssh` please. "When I try to install openssh-server I always have an error." What error? "while trying to install an older version of OpenSSH"  How? What steps did you use?

Comment: @muru output: 'ssh is /usr/local/bin/ssh', and I've inlcluded in the original post the steps I did and the error message.

Comment: You didn't include information on how did you install the old version. And what "this error" you have when you try to install openssh from Ubuntu repositories? Please [edit] your question and add this information.

Comment: @Pilot6 fixed. Actually I did edit the message, but then did a mistake and reverted it back :(

Comment: You need to uninstall it. You can run `sudo make uninstall` from the directory with that source code. otherwise you'll have to clean out manually.

Comment: @Pilot6 solved, THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `sudo make uninstall` from the directory with the old OpenSSH code.

That will uninstall the old version. Then you should be able to install OpenSSH from Ubuntu repositories.